# Unknown space below the div?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have seemed to encounter an unknown space below the div pair.
I have used the bootstrap grid concept and made use of rows and columns to have 2 adjacent Divs.
Then I have used CSS to make the div fill the whole space of the screen but I seem to get unaccounted for white space below the divs.

I have already tried including an advanced CSS reset.

Here is the html :

```css
#half_box_1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #FFAEAB;
}

#half_box_2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #FFC0FA;
}

#following_div {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
 <title>Kshitij Dhyani</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="materialize.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_portfolio.css">


 <!-- FONTS -->


</head>
<body>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6" id="half_box_1">asd</div>
  <div class="col-lg-6"
  id="half_box_2"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="following_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to comprehend this unaccounted space.
[image]

Comment: I can't see any space.

Comment: i don't see that space in `Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: Your problem must be somewhere else in your CSS, since I don't see any white spaces below your divs: https://jsfiddle.net/159syrze/

Comment: @user106328 I have used a bootstrap grid system, u need to include that if u want to see it here, hence I have added an image for more clarity.

Comment: @Kshitijdhyani  i think the jsfiddle by user Reza includes bootstrap 4 CSS file and the problems don't seem to be there either unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have somewhere in your CSS  the attributes `margin` or `padding` with values greater than 0?

Comment: can not able to see the space

Comment: if it's not possible to fully recreate your environment (although it probably should be), you can use something like chrome developer tools in your browser and inspect the elements' CSS, particularly `half_box_1`, `half_box_2` and `following_div` - you will be able to see if any padding or margins are present there (in chrome dev tools you can click on the `Computed` tab for a visual representation of this).  you might also want to consider using `height: 100vh` on the `row` class rather than `half_box_1` and `half_box_2`.

Comment: @user1063287 Thanks a lot buddy, I dived in the console and figured out that my row class had a bottom margin of 20 px.

Comment: @Kshitijdhyani , pleasure, excellent!

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably have noticed (by the comments), your code seems to work fine.

Your problem seems to be somewhere else in your CSS.

First, try to use the following CSS to see if it works:

```
* {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

If that worked, you can delete it and you need to start debugging.

Open up Chrome DevTools and go to **Sources** -> **Page** and find your CSS file(s). Try to delete each CSS block one after the other. If there is no more space between, you may found out where the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

this is default `margin`, Please add this code `body{margin: 0;padding: 0;}` in **css**